# Meteor Update Collection After Login

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm two weeks newbie for Meteor. I have some issue - I found my collection didn't update after I login.

```
    Meteor.subscribe("special",Meteor.userId());
```

Meteor.userId() suppose to be null and I can't get correct data. I'd also found this collection hadn't update after user login.

So I add bellow code -

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {

Meteor.subscribe("special",Meteor.userId());

/* update */
Accounts.onLogin(
    function() {
        Meteor.subscribe("special",Meteor.userId());
    }
);
```

}

I'm not sure about the policy of meteor. Did I break anything for this kind of code?

thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean it hasn't updated? what is 'it'? Also, what does the publish() function look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
Tracker.autorun(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe("special",Meteor.userId());
});
```

And in server side

```js
Meteor.publish("special", function() {
    if (this.userId) {
        // ... return Special.find() for instance
    } else {
        return [];
    }
});
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on the pattern - we subscribe to the collection and ask it to call us back after it loads

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  if ( Meteor.user() ){
    var sub = Meteor.subscribe('collection',function(){
      var object = collection.findOne(); // we won't get here until the collection is ready on the client
      ... do stuff ...
    });
  }
});
```